# How do you make an HTTP request to a WCF Service Application hosted with IIS?

Tags: wcf, http, rest, iis, host

To preface this, I have very little experience with servers and networking in general so I apologize if anything I say is incorrect or I am missing something simple.

I'm currently trying to create a WCF Service Application that I can make a HTTP request to from a different device on the same network and receive a response in the form of JSON. When I was using the Visual Studio Development Server to host the application I was able able to make these requests to my local host and get a response.

Request:

```
http://localhost:15021/Service1.svc/getData/myValue
```

Response:

```
{"GetDataResult":"You entered: myValue"}
```

Operation Contract:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getData/{value}")]
    string GetData(string value);
```

Although this worked from my machine, if I tried a different one, changing localhost with the machines IP address, I would get no response. I started looking into this and it would seem that I need to host this with IIS if I want this functionality. I found quite a few tutorials on hosting WCF services with IIS, ex. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/550796/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-How-to-Host-a-WCF-Service.

The problem with these tutorials was they always used a console based 'client' to run the contracts whereas I need to do so with an HTTP request. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I believe my web.config may be behind my issue, but not sure

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name ="MongoWCF.Service1" >
        <endpoint address="../Service1.svc"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="MongoWCF.IService1"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Initialy can you see the iis from the machine that the service is hosted?

Comment: Hosting the WCF service on a IIS is quite simple,on your WCF webservice project right click and select publish. just follow the simple steps and you should be able to host the WCF service on IIS. later use the same service address with appropriate ip address from remote client machine

Comment: You have to make it public. After that try to consume it from local server.

Comment: "I apologize if anything I say is incorrect or I am missing something simple". Please, no apologies for what you don't know. What we don't know is the reason we come here.

Comment: I am able to access the project url that Visual studio assigns when I use the 'Local IIS Web server' option and when I navigate to this url http://localhost/MongoWCF I am greeted with this HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.   Then  if I try to change the url to run the operation (I have tried many variations) http://localhost/MongoWCF/Service1.svc/getData/myValue   I get a 404 Error

Answer (score -1):

You need to use system IP Address to consume `WCF` service.

You can share the link of your svc file which looks like `http:// ip address here/Test/Service.svc`

The client can use this to generate proxy and consume your service.